# Function name must be a string in .../lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php:259 when I try to upload an image

Tags: admin, image-upload

I get this error:

```
Function name must be a string in  .../lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php:259
```

,when I try to upload an image. The media directory has been set to writable with `chmod -R 777 media` . What can be the cause for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOlved it. The problem was in uniform variable syntax, due to incompatibility between PHP 5 and PHP 7. I changed line 259 in Uploader.php from:

```
$params['object']->$params['method']($this->_file['tmp_name']);
```

to

```
$params['object']->{$params['method']}($this->_file['tmp_name']);
```

and problem is solved. If someone else wants to give an answer which better explains this, but also mentions my own found issue from this answer, feel free, otherwise I will accept my own answer in day or two (since this is a limitation when accepting one own's answer).

Comment: Great Solution :)