# Image Uploading Issue After Applying Patch 8788

Tags: magento-1, php-7, supee-8788v2

We are facing an issue of image upload in catalog product in admin after applying patch 8788. Please do not say clear magento cache, clear browser cache, flush CDN etc...etc...we already tried all these. We do not have CDN.

Please check the attached screenshot to see the jquery/javascript/json error that comes in console while uploading any image in product. It only says Uploading, then no process.

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue resolve by this :-

Go to `lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php` & change one line

From this:

```
$params['object']->$params['method']($this->_file['tmp_name']);
```

To this:

```
$params['object']->{$params['method']}($this->_file['tmp_name']);
```

Basically it is a compatibility issue between PHP 5 & 7.

Got the reference from here : [Function name must be a string in .../lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php:259 when I try to upload an image](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/148039/function-name-must-be-a-string-in-lib-varien-file-uploader-php259-when-i-tr)

Thank you.

Comment: If you are using `PHP7` there are some other things that have to be fixed! I strongly recommend this extension: https://github.com/Inchoo/Inchoo_PHP7

Comment: Thank you SV3N :) Yes we will definitely look at your suggested extension & will let you know.

Comment: Did you check Inchoo_PHP7?

Answer (score 1):

Just as "answer" ... if you are using PHP7 there are serveral other things that have to be fixed!

I strongly recommend using this extension: https://github.com/Inchoo/Inchoo_PHP7/